# JavaFX TreeView select(TreeItem<Object>) not working as expected

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

in the past I read lot's of hints, Tipps'n Tricks in this Forum. 
Now I try to ask my first question here :-)

I'm a bit new to JavaFX, but not new to Java. I'm trying to port an application from Swing to JavaFX so it will be more fancy and customizable.

The main Task of this program is to show two trees and compare them.
To make it easier I implemented in the old application a listener and celleditor to visualize the differences and when you select one Item in the one tree, it tries to find the corresponding Item in the other one. If it is not visible, it will be visible.

One screenshot to show the current application:
After the start it Looks like this and 
When selecting on the left, autoselect on the right and vice versa:
[Old application](https://www.zion-control.org/f/8efe9a3b6d/)

Now I try to implement the same Feature in JavaFX:
But using this code:

```
public void setOtherTree(TreeView<CompareNode> otherTree) {
    if (log.isTraceEnabled()) {
        log.trace("setOtherTree("+otherTree+")");
    }       
    this.otherTree = otherTree;

    tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
    tree.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable,oldValue,newValue) -> selectInOtherTree(newValue));
}

public void selectInOtherTree(TreeItem<CompareNode> newValue) {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug(logPrefix + " " + String.format("selectInOtherTree:newValue".replaceAll(", ", "=%s, ") + "=%s", newValue));
    }       
    otherTree.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    otherTree.getSelectionModel().select(newValue);
}
```

It always selects the item on an index base:
[Problem in JavaFX](https://www.zion-control.org/f/b553ded680/)

Am I missing something or is it a bug in JDK 1.8u45 (which I'm currently using)?

The class CompareNode overwrites toString, equals and hash

As I see, I need 10 reputations to post Images :-(, so I hope my words will explain it detailed enough or you can follow the links. **Sorry for that**

Any help is well appreciated.

Kind regards
Andreas

**2015-07-10 UPDATE:**
The two screenshots showing the old application:
[image: Overview of the tree]
[image: Selecting a node on the left, selects the same on the right]

And the screenshot of the new application:
[image]

Thanks for reputations :-)

**2015-09-22 UPDATE**

Meanwhile I create a Little demo app to demonstrate it.

TreeItemString.java

```
package application;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
public class TreeItemString extends TreeItem<String> {  
    public TreeItemString(String value) {
    this.setValue(value);
}   
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return this.getValue().equals(((TreeItemString) obj).getValu());
}   
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.getValue();
}   
@Override
public int hashCode() {     
    return this.getValue().hashCode();
}
}
```

MainApp.java

```
package application;    
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Main extends Application {    
    public void selectInOtherTree(TreeItem<String> toSelect, TreeView otherTree, TreeView thisTree) {
        System.out.println("Othertree : " + toSelect);
        System.out.println("Me : " + thisTree.getRow(toSelect));
        System.out.println("Other: " + otherTree.getRow(toSelect));
        otherTree.getSelectionModel().select(toSelect);
    }   
    public TreeItemString newRoot(TreeView<String> tree, Label label, String labelPrefix) {
        //Create TreeItems for the Hierarchy of the TreeView
        TreeItemString royalRoot = new TreeItemString("Queen Elizabeth - Prince Philip");    
        TreeItemString Charlie  = new TreeItemString("Prince Charles - Princess Diana");
        TreeItemString Annie = new TreeItemString("Princess Anne - Mark Phillips");
        TreeItemString Andy = new TreeItemString("Prince Andrew - Sarah Ferguson");
        TreeItemString Eddie = new TreeItemString("Prince Edward - Sophie");        
        //Populate the TreeItem to be used as the root with the other TreeItems
        royalRoot.getChildren().addAll(Charlie, Annie, Andy, Eddie);
        //Populate the other TreeItems with more TreeItems 
        //to build the family tree
        Charlie.getChildren().addAll(
                new TreeItemString("Prince William"), 
                new TreeItemString("Prince Henry"));        
        Annie.getChildren().addAll(
                new TreeItemString("Peter Phillips"), 
                new TreeItemString("Zara Phillips"));        
        Andy.getChildren().addAll(
                new TreeItemString("Princess Beatrice"), 
                new TreeItemString("Princess Eugenie"));        
        Eddie.getChildren().addAll(
                new TreeItemString("Lady Louise"), 
                new TreeItemString("Viscount Severn"));        
        return royalRoot;
    }   
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {        
       final String leftTreeLabelPrefix= "Selected Tree Item From left Tree: \n";
       final String rightTreeLabelPrefix = "Selected Tree Item From right Tree: \n";       
        //Use HBOX and VBOX layout panes to space out the controls
        //in a single row
        HBox treeBox = new HBox();
        VBox labelBox = new VBox(30);
        HBox controlBox = new HBox(10);        
        //Create labels to highlight the selected items from the TreeViews
        final Label leftTreeLabel = new Label(leftTreeLabelPrefix);
        final Label rightTreeLabel = new Label(rightTreeLabelPrefix);
        //Create and empty TreeView
        TreeView<String> leftTree = new TreeView<String>();                
        //Use the setRoot method to set the root TreeItem
//        duckTree.setRoot(duckRoot);
        leftTree.setRoot(newRoot(leftTree,leftTreeLabel, "Selected Tree Item From left Tree: \n"));        
        //Create a TreeView using the root TreeItem
        TreeView<String> rightTree = new TreeView<String>();
        rightTree.setRoot(newRoot(rightTree,rightTreeLabel, "Selected Tree Item From right Tree: \n"));        
        rightTree.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable,oldValue,newValue) -> selectInOtherTree(newValue, leftTree, rightTree));
        leftTree.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable,oldValue,newValue) -> selectInOtherTree(newValue, rightTree,leftTree));
        //Add the TreeViews to the HBox
        treeBox.getChildren().add(leftTree);
        treeBox.getChildren().add(rightTree);        
        //Add the labels to the VBox
        labelBox.getChildren().add(leftTreeLabel);
        labelBox.getChildren().add(rightTreeLabel);        
        //Add the HBox and VBox to another HBox to 
        //position the layout panes
        controlBox.getChildren().add(treeBox);
        controlBox.getChildren().add(labelBox);        
        //Add the main HBOX layout pane to the scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(controlBox, 800, 250);
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        Thread backGroundThread = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    System.out.println("Select left Viscount Severn");
                    leftTree.getRoot().setExpanded(true);
                    leftTree.getRoot().getChildren().get(1).setExpanded(true);
                    leftTree.getRoot().getChildren().get(2).setExpanded(true);
                    leftTree.getRoot().getChildren().get(3).setExpanded(true);
                    TreeItemString toSearch = new TreeItemString("Prince Edward - Sophie");
                    System.out.println("true:false for : " + toSearch);
                    System.out.println("true:false : " + leftTree.getRoot().getChildren().contains(toSearch));
                    System.out.println("indexOf: " + leftTree.getRoot().getChildren().indexOf(toSearch));
                    System.out.println("get: " + leftTree.getRoot().getChildren().get(leftTree.getRoot().getChildren().indexOf(toSearch)));
                    System.out.println("getRow: " + leftTree.getRow(leftTree.getRoot().getChildren().get(leftTree.getRoot().getChildren().indexOf(toSearch))));
                    leftTree.getSelectionModel().select(new TreeItemString("Princess Anne - Mark Phillips"));
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    System.out.println("Select right Princess Beatrice");
                    rightTree.getSelectionModel().select(new TreeItemString("Princess Beatrice"));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
       });  
        backGroundThread.setDaemon(true);
        backGroundThread.start();
        //Show the form
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: The links are not working. Upload them to imgur.com and post the link.

Comment: Or upload them to the question directly, since you now have sufficient reputation.

Comment: Can you show the `CompareNode .equals(...)` method because it is used to find out the row in the Tree.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delay. I updated the post.